# Android google map routing by reading KML

Tags: android

How to draw route path on MapView Google API. I have two ordinates. Please tell options to draw path between these two points

Answer (score 0):

REFER THIS [LINK](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-draw-route-map-between-two.html)

**SharedData.java**

```
package com.agarwal.route;



public class SharedData {

    // this is a singleton class that provides a global data share for all of the 
    // activities and services in the MDWrapper application        
    private static SharedData instance = null;


    private SharedData() {
        //randomizeServers();
    }

    // data to be shared
    private String APIKEY = "";
    private double src_lat = -1;
    private double src_lng = -1;
    private double dest_lat = -1;
    private double dest_lng = -1;

    /**
     * @return the aPIKEY
     */
    public String getAPIKEY() {
        return APIKEY;
    }

    /**
     * @param aPIKEY the aPIKEY to set
     */
    public void setAPIKEY(String aPIKEY) {
        APIKEY = aPIKEY;
    }

    /**
     * @return the src_lat
     */
    public double getSrc_lat() {
        return src_lat;
    }

    /**
     * @param src_lat the src_lat to set
     */
    public void setSrc_lat(double src_lat) {
        this.src_lat = src_lat;
    }

    /**
     * @return the src_lng
     */
    public double getSrc_lng() {
        return src_lng;
    }

    /**
     * @param src_lng the src_lng to set
     */
    public void setSrc_lng(double src_lng) {
        this.src_lng = src_lng;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dest_lat
     */
    public double getDest_lat() {
        return dest_lat;
    }

    /**
     * @param dest_lat the dest_lat to set
     */
    public void setDest_lat(double dest_lat) {
        this.dest_lat = dest_lat;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dest_lng
     */
    public double getDest_lng() {
        return dest_lng;
    }

    /**
     * @param dest_lng the dest_lng to set
     */
    public void setDest_lng(double dest_lng) {
        this.dest_lng = dest_lng;
    }

    public static SharedData getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new SharedData();
        }

        return instance;
    }

}
```

**CustomItemizedOverlay.java**

```
package com.agarwal.route;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private final ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();


    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mapOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mapOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
        this.populate();
    }

}
```

**MyOverLay.java**

```
package com.agarwal.route;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;

public class MyOverLay extends Overlay 
{ 
    private GeoPoint gp1; 
    private GeoPoint gp2; 
    private int mode=0; 
    private int defaultColor; 
    Context mContext;

    public MyOverLay(Context context,GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode) // GeoPoint is a int. (6E) 
    { 
        this.gp1 = gp1; 
        this.gp2 = gp2; 
        this.mode = mode; 
        this.mContext = context;
        defaultColor = 999; // no defaultColor 

    } 

    public MyOverLay(GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode, int defaultColor) 
    { 
        this.gp1 = gp1; 
        this.gp2 = gp2; 
        this.mode = mode; 
        this.defaultColor = defaultColor; 
    }  
    public int getMode() 
    { 
        return mode; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean draw 
    (Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) 
    { 
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection(); 
        if (shadow == false) 
        { 
            Paint paint = new Paint(); 
            paint.setAntiAlias(true); 
            Point point = new Point(); 
            projection.toPixels(gp1, point); 
            // mode=1&#65306;start 
            if(mode==1) 
            { 
                if(defaultColor==999) 
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
                else 
                    paint.setColor(defaultColor);                
                // start point
            } 
            // mode=2&#65306;path 
            else if(mode==2) 
            { 
                if(defaultColor==999) 
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
                else 
                    paint.setColor(defaultColor); 
                Point point2 = new Point(); 
                projection.toPixels(gp2, point2); 
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5); 
                paint.setAlpha(120); 
                canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint); 

            } 
            /* mode=3&#65306;end */ 
            else if(mode==3) 
            { 
                /* the last path */ 

                if(defaultColor==999) 
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
                else 
                    paint.setColor(defaultColor); 
                Point point2 = new Point(); 
                projection.toPixels(gp2, point2); 
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5); 
                paint.setAlpha(120); 
                canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint); 
                /* end point */

            } 
        } 
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when); 
    } 

}
```

**RoutePath.java**

```
package com.agarwal.route;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;


public class RoutePath extends MapActivity { 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    MapView mapView;
    private RoutePath _activity;
    GeoPoint srcGeoPoint,destGeoPoint;
    private static List<Overlay> mOverlays;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedData data = SharedData.getInstance();
        mapView = new MapView(this,data.getAPIKEY());
        mapView.setClickable(true);        
        setContentView(mapView); 
        _activity = this;
        double src_lat = data.getSrc_lat();
        double src_long = data.getSrc_lng();
        double dest_lat = data.getDest_lat();
        double dest_long = data.getDest_lng();

        if(src_lat == -1 || src_long == -1 || dest_lat == -1 || dest_long == -1){
            showAlert("Please enter source and destination points");
        }else{

            srcGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (src_lat * 1E6),(int) (src_long * 1E6)); 
            destGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (dest_lat * 1E6),(int) (dest_long * 1E6)); 

            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            Drawable srcdrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_green);
            CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(srcdrawable);
            //CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(getDrawable("com/agarwal/route/pin_green.png"));
            OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(srcGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");

            Drawable destdrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_red);
            CustomItemizedOverlay  destitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay( destdrawable );
           // CustomItemizedOverlay destitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(getDrawable("com/agarwal/route/pin_red.png"));
            OverlayItem destoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(destGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is dest Location.");

            srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem);
            destitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(destoverlayitem);

            mapOverlays.add(srcitemizedOverlay);
            mapOverlays.add(destitemizedOverlay);

            connectAsyncTask _connectAsyncTask = new connectAsyncTask();
            _connectAsyncTask.execute();        
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
            mOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            mapView.getController().animateTo(srcGeoPoint); 
            mapView.getController().setZoom(12); 
        } 
    }
    @Override 
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        return false; 
    } 

    private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_activity);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fetchData();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);            
            if(doc!=null){
                Overlay ol = new MyOverLay(_activity,srcGeoPoint,srcGeoPoint,1);
                mOverlays.add(ol);
                NodeList _nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
                Node node1 = _nodelist.item(0);
                String _status1  = node1.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                if(_status1.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
                    NodeList _nodelist_path = doc.getElementsByTagName("overview_polyline");
                    Node node_path = _nodelist_path.item(0);
                    Element _status_path = (Element)node_path;
                    NodeList _nodelist_destination_path = _status_path.getElementsByTagName("points");
                    Node _nodelist_dest = _nodelist_destination_path.item(0);
                    String _path  = _nodelist_dest.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    List<GeoPoint> _geopoints = decodePoly(_path);
                    GeoPoint gp1; 
                    GeoPoint gp2; 
                    gp2 = _geopoints.get(0);
                    Log.d("_geopoints","::"+_geopoints.size());
                    for(int i=1;i<_geopoints.size();i++) // the last one would be crash 
                    { 

                        gp1 = gp2;
                        gp2 = _geopoints.get(i);
                        Overlay ol1 = new MyOverLay(gp1,gp2,2,Color.BLUE);
                        mOverlays.add(ol1);
                    } 
                    Overlay ol2 = new MyOverLay(_activity,destGeoPoint,destGeoPoint,3);
                    mOverlays.add(ol2);

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }else{
                    showAlert("Unable to find the route");
                }

                Overlay ol2 = new MyOverLay(_activity,destGeoPoint,destGeoPoint,3);
                mOverlays.add(ol2);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                mapView.scrollBy(-1,-1);
                mapView.scrollBy(1,1);
            }else{
                showAlert("Unable to find the route");
            }

        }

    }
    Document doc = null;
    private void fetchData()
    {
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=");
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)srcGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
        urlString.append(","); 
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)srcGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
        urlString.append("&destination=");//to 
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)destGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
        urlString.append(","); 
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)destGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
        urlString.append("&sensor=true&mode=driving");     
        Log.d("url","::"+urlString.toString());
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null; 
        URL url = null; 
        try 
        { 
            url = new URL(urlString.toString()); 
            urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); 
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true); 
            urlConnection.connect(); 
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = (Document) db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());//Util.XMLfromString(response);
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }catch (IOException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private List<GeoPoint> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<GeoPoint> poly = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (((double) lat / 1E5) * 1E6),
                    (int) (((double) lng / 1E5) * 1E6));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
    private void showAlert(String message){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_activity);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setMessage(message);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
    private Drawable getDrawable(String fileName){
        return Drawable.createFromStream(_activity.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName), "pin");
    }
}
```

In Your Activity Just Paste the below few lines to draw routemap:

```
SharedData data = SharedData.getInstance();
data.setAPIKEY("0RUTLH7cqd6yrZ0FdS0NfQMO3lioiCbnH-BpNQQ");
data.setSrc_lat(17);
data.setSrc_lng(78);
data.setDest_lat(18);
data.setDest_lng(77);
startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,RoutePath.class));
```

**Note::** Need to RoutePath activity and permssions in your manifeast file

Comment: The apikey in SharedData,java is same to the data.setAPIKEY() in the bottom of your answer?

Comment: This code was written by the old Google Maps API v1 which was depreciated in Dec.2012. To implement this on the new API v2, some codes must be modified again.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer link [Android Driving Direction](http://csie-tw.blogspot.in/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html).
Full description is given there with source that you can download from [source link 1](http://webtoolplus.com/downloads/RoutePath.zip.) or [source link 2](http://www.mediafire.com/?tlfshkkq58l38p1#)